# calling same functions in multiple times with different arguments python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input file in two different cases:

```
case1:

inputfile:

one-device:yes
number of device:01-05
first-device:
second-device:

Case2:
one-device:no
number of device:01-05
first-device:01-03
second-device:04-05
```

Now in case 1 i have only one start and end value that is 01 and 05

Functions I have is:

```
def func1(self, start, end):
     for i, x in enumerate (range(start, end)):
         do something
def func10 (self, start, end):
         do something

case 2: i have 2 different start and end value that is for first device 01-03 and 04-05.
```

In case 1 my program execution flow.

```
# if one-device input is yes
func1(arg1, agr2)
func2(arg1, agr2)
func3(arg1, agr2)
func4(arg1, agr2)
func5(arg1, agr2)
func6(arg1, agr2)
func7(arg1, agr2)
func8(arg1)
func9(arg1, agr2,arg3)
func10(agr1,arg2)
func11(arg1, agr2)
func12(arg1, agr2)
func13(arg1) 


#if one-device input is no.
#In  case2. i need to call two times functions func1 and func10.
```

my program execution flow like for case 2 is:

```
# run two times with two diffewnt start and end values as per input in case 2
func1(arg1, agr2)
func1(arg1, agr2)


#flow continues as usal 
func2(arg1, agr2)
func3(arg1, agr2)
func4(arg1, agr2)
func5(arg1, agr2)
func6(arg1, agr2)
func7(arg1, agr2)
func8(arg1)
func9(arg1, agr2,arg3)
# run two times with two diffewnt start and end values as per input in case 2
func10(agr1,arg2)
func10(agr1,arg2)


#flow continues as usal 
func11(arg1, agr2)
func12(arg1, agr2)
func13(arg1)


Now question is i want to use if else statement to check one-device is yes or no.

if one-device  is yes  write case 1  flow

if one-device  is no  write case 1  flow 

if no write same flow with using for loop for func1 and func10 to run two  times.

If i use this method my code be be lot of duplicate .

I need help here
```

Comment: Can't you just pass it like this: `func3(user_input)`?

Comment: You want same function to get multiple different arguments? And you don't know how much you're going to get?

Comment: @ Adeel Ahmad no,  We can't  be use like that. based user input many arguments values is going to change

Comment: @s_vishnu,  same functions get different arguments yes. I know what arguments going to change based on input

Comment: @Bittu Can you give an example input and output? Also check my answer.

Comment: I am not able put my question in right way i am going to delete this questions thanks a lot for support. let me put in different way next time

Comment: @Bittu You just have to give an example input/output. But sure, thanks for relying on the community :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood the question. But from what I understood, I think you want the function to be able to accept variable number of arguments:

```
def f1(arg1, *args):
    print "first arg: ", arg1
    for arg in args:
        print "next arg:", arg

f1(1, "string", 3,4)
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for?